# Covering Class and Describing Outer MEasure for General Measures

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

I am uncertain if my description is correct, but I describe the measure in a piecewise type fashion. In general,

$\mu_{\lambda}^*(A) = \infty$, if $A = X$ or $A$ uncountable.

$\mu_{\lambda}^*(A) = |A|$, if $\emptyset \not = A \subseteq X$ but not equal to $X$.

Comment: How did you reach your conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer measure $\mu^*_\lambda$ is the counting measure.

If $\emptyset\neq A\subset X$, we can cover it in essentially two ways using $\kappa$: using $X$ or using singletons.
If we use $X$, we always get infinite measure, so it suffices to study what happens when covering with singletons.
If we use singletons, we get the number of points (since $\lambda$ assigns measure one to each point and you can only cover one point at a time with $\kappa$).
If $A$ is infinite, we get infinity either way so $\mu^*_\lambda(A)=\infty$.
But if $A$ is finite, covering by singletons shows that $\mu^*_\lambda(A)=\#A$ (the number of points in $A$).
If $X$ itself is finite, we get $\mu^*_\lambda(X)<\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking right when I wrote this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is counting measure?  The definition of $\, \mu^{*}_{\lambda}$ is that it assigns every proper nonempty subset of $X$ the value $1$.  (Well, every nonempty proper subset of $X$ that is in the collection $\mathcal{K}$.)  How do you show that the measure of a finite set is the number of elements in $A$?  I guess my question is how is $\, \mu^{*}_{\lambda}$ defined for non-empty proper subsets of $X$ that contain more than one element.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot, suppose $\#A=3$. Then if you use the singletons, you need three sets in $\kappa$ to cover $A$. (If you want to use something other than singletons, the only thing available is $X$ which gives infinity.) Since $\lambda$ gives measure one to each of these singletons, you get $\mu^*_\lambda(A)=3$. The infimum in the definition of $\mu^*_\lambda$ is actually a minimum for these $\lambda$ and $\kappa$.

Comment: Why do you assume that $\mu^{*}_{\lambda}$ assigns the infimum of the lengths of open covers to subsets of $X$ with more than one element?  Is that what all outer measures do?  It is not explicitly mentioned in the problem, so I wasn't sure if outer measures can be formulated in another way...

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot, it is a standard thing. The question comes in a context where the reader is supposed to know the canonical way of constructing an outer measure from a premeasure (or other measure-like things). The construction in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Method_I

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Oh ok.  Thanks for your responses.